# Modifying and releasing Windows-XP code

Tags: licensing, copyright

Am I legally allowed to modify (remove bloatware, rewrite functions etc.) to leaked code and release it online for free? I don't intend to license anything, it's just mostly for a personal project to extend windows XP compatibility to some modern applications.

Comment: What makes you think you might possibly be allowed to take illegally released code and use it for _anything_?

Comment: Because I legally own a copy of the compiled version of this code. Also I am not planning on making any money off of it.

Comment: This seems to be nothing to do with open-source code then, so is off-topic for this site. You could ask on Law.SE but that answer is "blatant no", you have no right to modify proprietary software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Free/Open Source software.

Comment: Wait. Microsoft isn't open source? I thought all the forced updates and shady attempts to switch everyone over to edge we're all in the name of sharing their sources with everyone. I just always assumed that they forgot to include the decompiler...  Who knew?  Xp

Comment: Wow, that was meant to be in emoticon. Didn't even think about the question being about XP. If only I could plan quips as clever as the ones into which I fall axe backward, I would be set!

Comment: @BobJoe so what...? I can legally own a copy of, let's say, *Justin Bieber's Greatest Hits*, that doesn't mean I'm allowed to copy it and give copies to all my friends and neighbours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operative word here is **leaked**. Microsoft never intended to release the code for Windows XP or to make it open.
If it was illegally distributed, and continued distribution of it, modified or not, would also probably be illegal.